# Xcode SVN - do you really have to import every new file?

Tags: svn, xcode

You can commit and update already existing files in Xcode - great. But when someone else creates a new file and adds it to the repository, there seems to be no way to refresh Xcode so that it recognizes it, even after "update entire project". The files are added in Finder, but to get them into Xcode you have to manually import them. Am I missing something or is this a huge flaw in Xcode? Other IDEs (FlashDevelop for example) have a Refresh option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the project (solution/makefile or whatever the equivalent in XCode) should be updated and checked-in at the same time by the person who added new files to it.

Comment: Those files are always in conflict though because everyone is modifying their project files simultaneously.